# String reversal in C++ getting 'Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c++, string, recursion

This below gives me 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error after printing the reversed string. Can anyone explain why ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void print (char *str) {
    if (*str) {
        print (str+1);
        cout << *str;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *str;
    cin >> str;
    print(str);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your debugger might be able to. At the very least, it has a good chance of slimming this code sample down to two lines.

Comment: `str` has never had memory allocated.

Comment: You need to declare memory for `str`.

Comment: But it does print the reversed string. Why is that happening ?

Comment: Undefined Behavior is why it prints anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninitialized non-static local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and will in reality be seemingly random. Using them without initialization leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is one of the most common causes of crashes.

The problem is that you have a pointer, but it doesn't point anywhere so when you use it to read input, the input stream `cin` will write to a random location in memory.

The solution is to not use character pointers for string, but the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

---

If you *have* to use pointers, then you have two solutions: Either declare the string as an array, or allocate memory using the `new` operator. However be cautioned that if you input more than you have allocated you will write out of bounds and once again have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory to `char *str`. Try using `char str[20]` (20 is just an example, it could be anything as per your demand and your machine's capability) and everything will be fine. You are assuming that compiler will allocate memory for you but that's not the case. You are trying to access an unallocated memory or you can dynamically allocate them using `malloc` or `new`.

More than that you can use `std::string` to do get help from stl.

Comment: ***Try using char str[20] and everything will be*** As long as the user types 19 or fewer characters.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `scanf("%19s", str);`? or  does the `std::string str; cin >> str;` work?

Comment: @drescherjm Ofcourse it is. I have just pointed the error asap. Thanks for pointing out. I will modify my answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Either declare the `str` like `char str[fixed_size]` or use std::string. One of the simplest methods to do that might be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    cout <<str<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```